# Acer Aspire issues with suspending and screen flickering (Ubuntu, and Kubuntu 19.10)

Tags: boot, 19.10

There are 2 major issues I'm currently having with the kernel that Ubuntu has installed.

The first, and biggest issue is with suspension. When I shut the lid, or make it sleep, it never comes back. I can't get it to load a login screen or anything. It just sits there, with the screen off. It also sits there on like that when I try to shut it down and restart it as well.

The 2nd issue is during usage, the screen will occasionally flicker, which is also very annoying. I've tried downgrading the kernel until I stopped seeing the issue (to 4.15) but that breaks the wi-fi. This currently is proving to become very unusable, and I'm very worried on how things will work for me when 20.04 comes out. Does anyone have a solution to this? Thanks in advance! :)

CPU: AMD A9-4200M
Grahpics: [Integrated Radeon R5 graphics of the processor](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors/2541,2546,2551,4046,4041,3361,3356,3306,3301,2526,2531,2536,5671,5786,5661,5661)
Model: [Acer Aspire A315-21-95KF](https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2017/4876/A315-21/NX.GNVAA.002.html)

Comment: https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2017/4876/A315-21/NX.GNVAA.002.html  this link should provide information about the model. All the stuff on that page is accurate for my laptop except for the storage, I put an SSD drive in my computer, but that shouldn't change anything in this instance.

Comment: Bump? I really need this bug to be sorted out. It's preventing me from using Ubuntu, at all. I can't use an OS that where basic functions don't work.